# SimpleDateFormat in Servlets

Tags: java, servlets, simpledateformat, thread-local

I'm using a lot of SimpleDateFormat-objects within my Servlet. Unfortunately, SimpleDateFormat is not thread-safe. Thus, I thought about wrapping it wih ThreadLocal to foster the reuse of SimpleDateFormat-objects. I wrote an util-class to enable this:

```
public class DateUtil {
    private final static ThreadLocal<SimpleDateFormat> dateFormat = new ThreadLocal<SimpleDateFormat>() {
        return new SimpleDateFormat();
    }

    public static SimpleDateFormat get () {
        return dateFormat.get();
    }
}
```

Actually, this seems to lead to a memory-leak. When shutting down my webapp, Tomcat logs the following error message:

> SEVERE: The web application [] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [null] (value [com.example.util.DateUtil$2@50242f7d]) and a value of type [java.text.SimpleDateFormat] (value [java.text.SimpleDateFormat@d91b489b]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. This is very likely to create a memory leak.

I understand the reason for the memory-leak, but what is the best way to handle SimpleDateFormat-objects (or any other non-thread-safe objects) within Servlets?

Comment: I understand I am not the one supposed to be asking a question in a commnet, but what is the reason for memory leak? Thanks in advance to you.

Comment: The reason is that an instance SimpleDateFormat will be held against each request thread that happens to run this code, at no point will that instance be removed.

Comment: 10 years late on this, but won't the instance be removed when the webapp stops and the class is unloaded? Given it's a final static field

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aside from using an alternative implementation ([commons-lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/time/FastDateFormat.html) or [joda](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/)) just create a new instance of `SimpleDateFormat` each time you what to use it.

I realise that this will make you feel dirty and in need of a bath, but it is very simple and doesn't require any effort on your part. The downside is that you will turn over a little bit more memory than before but in most normal web applications you are unlikely to notice against the noise of JDBC.

See my answer to [ThreadLocal Resource Leak and WeakReference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940506/threadlocal-resource-leak-and-weakreference/940855#940855)

Comment: It should be mentioned, that `SimpleDateFormat` is expensive to create (it creates a `Calendar` instance internally). See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4107839/synchronizing-access-to-simpledateformat

Comment: expensive is a relative term, if like the user in http://www.thedwick.com/blog/2008/04/simpledateformat-performance-pig/ you are seemly doing nothing but parsing dates then it could be expensive, but if you are putting 20 dates on a html page after running a jdbc/hibernate query it really isn't going to be that important. Make sure your program is correct *first* then make it fast.

Answer (score 3):

Create local objects or use [FastDateFormat](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/time/FastDateFormat.html) (FastDateFormat is a fast and thread-safe version of SimpleDateFormat.) from commons-lang. And joda-time is a common answer to all the date related questions ;-)